# iOS 5 storyboard, programmatically determine path

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard

I'm having trouble to achieve the following using a storyboard:

When setup is not done:
run app -> show settings view controller -> show main navigation controller
When setup is done:
run app -> show main navigation controller

So basically, I want the app to programmatically start with the settings view in certain cases, and otherwise skip right ahead to the main navigation controller.

I did manage to show the settings view with a modal style segue from the main navigation controller, but I don't know how to display it *before* the main navigation controller is displayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I managed to do it a bit different:

1. Use a `UINavigationController` as the initial view controller.
2. Create a root view controller that will manage the decision of what to load.
3. Create a Storyboard Segues from the root view controller to the main view and to settings view, and give the segues proper identifiers.
4. Call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` with the proper identifier from your root view controller.

Just another solution, hope this helps.

Comment: this is better and easier way to tackle the problem i feel

Comment: Agreed, this seems like a better solution. I've changed the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't think this will work if you are using a split view controller in your application - the split view controller needs to be the initial root.

Comment: Isn't there will be a Back button on main/settings view controller, that will lead to empty view controller?

Answer (score 29):

By default, the initial view controller from your main storyboard is instantiated and displayed automatically when your app starts up. To prevent this happening you need to remove the `UIMainStoryboardFile` setting from your info.plist file.

With no default view controller, you are now free to create one programmatically at app startup. See the [UIStoryboard documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Use `+storyboardWithName:bundle:` to load the storyboard and then use `–instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to create the correct view controller. You will also need to create a main UIWindow and add the view controller's view to it just like you used to do with .nib based UI. Note that without the `UIMainStoryboardFile` setting a main window is not created for you - read the [explanation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW9).

Comment: Thanks, removing the storyboard from the info.plist did the trick!

Comment: How to create the main `UIWindow` ?

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar to amoshaviv, his advice is sound. I did it slightly different though, and I'll give some more info.
I created a custom MyInitialViewController class, derived from UIViewController, and made this the initial view controller.
In the storyboard file, I created modal segues with appropriate names to all (in my case three) possible 'real' first view controllers.
In the MyInitialViewController class, I implemented the

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

method, to first perform the check which view to switch to, and then do the correct

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NameOfSegue" sender:self];
```

Effectively, this makes the MyInitialViewController nothing more than a switch performed when it's brought into view. I first tried doing this when loaded because I don't care for actually seeing this view, but that did not work, while viewDidAppear does.

To make this visually smooth, I tried the following. In the properties of the segues, I disabled animation. The view I left empty, and I gave it a background color matching to that of the startup image.