# iPhone 5 Image Issuses

Tags: iphone, uiimage, ios6

I have an app that I am making but the background image I am using wont work on my iPhone 5. Everything works on it when I load it on my iPhone 4. It was size the     -568h@2x.png right it looks massive or it will load the     @2x.png and give it a tile look. Any one know would could be wrong. I've tried making a UIImage in IB and programmatically. Neither have been successful. I've even tried if else methods to loads different pngs based on the screen height. I'm at a point where I could just quit. Any direction or guidance. I have all my code but didn't know what would be the best pice to post.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might need to make two separate storyboards/xibs, one for an iPhone 5 and another for the iPhone 4S/4/3GS, etc. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536689/xcode-4-5-how-to-pick-storyboards-at-launch) that will tell you how to do it.