# How to use XCode 5 Autolayout for container views?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, autolayout

I've spent sleepless nights trying to follow every tutorial there is about xcode 5's autolayout feature but I cannot do it myself.

Here's screenshots:

Pic 1: All constraints are cleared in view.

[image]

Pic 2: Add 'Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide' to container view and two buttons.

[image]

Pic 3: So these are all the constraints I have.

[image]

Pic 4: when I resize view to 3.5 inch nothing works.

[image]

Comment: Make sure all the constraints are present to avoid ambiguity and are referring to the right edge in the right reference frame.

Comment: @gturri I don't have any code, I didn't think you needed any code when using Autolayout

Comment: @HM1 so "add missing constraints"?

Comment: See [Add Missing Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH8-SW1) and [Resolving AutoLayout Issues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH17-SW1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the best answer to be this:

Make a new storyboard specifically for 3.5 inch screens then in app delegate, just say if (some definition of iphone 5) then display main storyboard, else display the 3.5 inch one.

Here's a more in depth explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12537190/2948421

Answer (score 1):

i think you are adding two button (login +register) as subViews to some view (say whiteView) which has white backGround.
If above is true, then add a pin of "`bottomSpace to superview`" to that whiteView. so it always keeps the same distance from superView from bottom.

Comment: No they're just UIButtons on a view controller's view?