# Cannot find (secondary) storyboard named Test.storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, ios10

I would like to load a secondary storyboard `Test.storyboard` (next to `Main.storyboard`) in my app like so:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Test.storyboard", bundle: nil)
```

`Test.storyboard` resides inside a group `Test`, it is marked for localization as Base (hence its Location Relative to Group is reported as `Base.lproj/Test.storyboard`) and it also marked for target membership in my app target. When I run the app on the simulator, I can confirm that a file `Base.lproj/Test.storyboardc` exists inside the app's main bundle.

Yet the above code produces this error:

```
Could not find a storyboard named 'Test.storyboard' in bundle ...
```

What is the right way to successfully package and load a secondary storyboard like mine?

Comment: i think its helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24840376/6619234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to load storyboard with .storyboard extension .use like this

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Test", bundle: nil)
```