# How to go from one view controller in One storyboard to another viewcontroller in another storyboard programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3

I have a view controller A in the Storyboard named "X" in it i have a button . On clicking it I am checking the success response for the API and after that I need to navigate to the view controller B in the storyboard "B" .

I am using the code:

```
let loginstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
let loginController = loginstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as? LoginViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginController!, animated: true)
```

So it is not working for me. What is the issue?

Comment: check if the storyboard and viewcontroller identifier names are correct

Comment: add the code where you are calling API and handing response as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840306/how-to-call-different-storyboards-via-swift-for-ios

Comment: Does view controller A belong to a NavigationController in Storyboard?

Comment: Check if none of them are nil like loginstoryboard,logincontroller and navigationcontroller,if you are making API call in background thread,then  put above code in main thread

Comment: @YunCHEN yes it belongs to a navigation controller

Comment: Could you show the code for creating View Controller A?

Comment: Just check:
-> if you have a login.storyBoard
-> self.navigationController is valid means does it belongs here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below steps.

1. Check your both view controllers **StoryboardID** (If Storyboard ID is already inserted then skip step 2).
2. Insert View controller **StoryboardID**

Please check sample image of StoryboardID

[image]

Sample Code

```
   UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:"YourStoryBoardName" bundle:nil];
   UIViewController  *loginViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:"LoginViewController"];
   // If Login View Controller is not a Navigation Controller then you need to create Navigation Controller
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:true];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create reference of your story board programmatically below thenceforth instantiate viewcontroller using its storyboard id.

```
 let loginstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
```

In Storyboard 
You can even reference a view controller in an external storyboard.Refer [@bshirley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297701/using-multiple-storyboards-in-ios) ans for detailed explanation.