# Change storyboard programmatically in Swift 3

Tags: swift, storyboard, transition, viewcontroller

I'm working in GameScene but I want to transition to View Controller3. I currently have

```
if ball.position.y <= block1.position.y - 70 {
    let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View Controller3") as! ViewController3
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but this gives me the error

> "Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'storyboard'"

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840306/how-to-call-different-storyboards-via-swift-for-ios