# How to move from a view controller into other view controller in storyboard programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have create two view controller onto storyboard I wanted to go from one view controller to another view controller programmatically. I have create a button in one view controller. I know it very easy to go from one view controller to another just drag line from button from oneviewcontroller to second view controller. but I want to do it programmatically because I have if and else conditions in button when if condition true then I want to move it to next view controller this is the code.

```
-(IBAction)loadView:(id)sender {
    if([username.text isEqualToString:@"adnan"] && [password.text isEqualToString:@"bhatti123"] )
    {
        // here I want to write that code which reach me to second view controller which I implement on storyboard 

    }   
    else 
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag line from first view controller to second and set the identifier for segue:

[image]

In the `.m` file:

```
if([username.text isEqualToString:@"adnan"] && [password.text isEqualToString:@"bhatti123"] )
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextView" sender:sender];
}   
else 
{

}
```

Comment: you're great man you know what i want love u man thanks a lot

Comment: How to pass values to next view controller using this method?

Comment: @Aniruddha, you need write method `prepareForSegue:sender:` in first view controller and get `destinationViewController`, which is an instance of next view controller. You can access its properties and pass values. ([Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8597092/683917)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). I got to know that `[performSegue.....]` will in turn calls the `prepareforSegue....`.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)loadView:(id)sender
{
      if([username.text isEqualToString:@"adnan"] && [password.text isEqualToString:@"bhatti123"] )
      {
         // here i want to write that code which reach me to second view controller which i implement on storyboard 
            SecondViewController *objSecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondViewController animated:YES];
            [objSecondViewController release];
     }   
     else 
     { 
        //write your else part code here
     }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 
SecondViewController *objSecondViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: BUT HOW I CAN KNOW ON STORYBOARD THAT THIS IS THE NIB FILE ON STORYBOARD THERE ARE MORE THEN ONE VIEW CONTROLLER ON STORYBOARD THEN HOW I INIT SECONDVIEWCONTROLLER WITH INITWITHNIBNAME

Comment: then simply set the class and push or present it.. also when you create nib at that time you give the name to the nib right??

Comment: @AdnanQadir also see this answer dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889510/ios-5-storyboard-programmatically-determine-path :)

Comment: can i need to define property for storyboard secondviewcontroller dude

Comment: @AdnanQadir Please fix your caps lock key.

Comment: no instead of it use your viewcontroller name dude try and do something with this code

Comment: i set set breakpoint and run the debugger and debugger giving sigabrd error at this line [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondViewController animated:YES];

Comment: for this type of issues see this tutorial http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/debugging.html but i think u not assign name of class or instance properly dude.. just see the code and set class which you want to go to nextview...

Comment: also refer this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889510/ios-5-storyboard-programmatically-determine-path

Comment: @ParasJoshi how to pass values to next view controller using this method? I tried `SecondViewController *sc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; sc.strName = @"Abcd"; [self presentviewController:sc animation:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: @Aniruddha you used storyboard in your project ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Storyboard. I have 2 classes A and B. From A, I want to pass the value to B. This is how I done it but it is not working. `B *bb = [[B alloc]init]; b.strName = @"Abcd"; [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:nil];`

Comment: @Aniruddha try it out this one in `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`  method      `B *bb=segue.destinationViewController;b.strName = @"Abcd";`

Comment: I got to know how to do it. `[performSegueWithI....]` in turn calls `prepareForSegue...`. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SecondViewController *secondviewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self presentviewController:secondviewController animation:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: BUT HOW I CAN KNOW ON STORYBOARD THAT THIS IS THE NIB FILE ON STORYBOARD THERE ARE MORE THEN ONE VIEW CONTROLLER ON STORYBOARD THEN HOW I INIT SECONDVIEWCONTROLLER WITH INITWITHNIBNAME

Comment: dear there are more then one view controller on storyboard i don't wanna create new uiview using object